# on edit in grid, datepicker field is not displaying default value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

If i click on EDIT in GridView, after that i am getting 2 dropdownlist , text field and 3 datepickers.. 
if pick date only in one datepicker field then i m getting error(different error for different fields). if i pick all datepickers then update is working..

aspx.cs code for datepicker::

```
   DatePicker dp1 = (DatePicker)row.FindControl("DatePicker5");
   DateTime date_withdrawn = Convert.ToDateTime(dp1.CalendarDateString);

    DatePicker dp2 = (DatePicker)row.FindControl("DatePicker7");
    DateTime date_delivered = dp2.CalendarDate;
```

Comment: I think you have not selected the date for second date picker and your are trying to get the date value. so it is throwing error.

Comment: Thing is like that.. I have one page. In that page, there is one grid and some input fields. Grid is bind to database. during input field values, i am not selecting two datepicker values. so, by default the value in database for them is 1/1/0001.

Comment: on editing that row, if is select all the datepicker values then everything works fine.. but if i select only one or two not third then i am getting error..

Comment: Can you please add your code here ?

Comment: i have fixed that problem.. needed to provide some default value..